# running asyntask concurrently (android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to have a asynctask to run in the background and the other one to load something from the webservice to have a new listview.

Here is my code.

AsyncCallForwardListWS

```
private class AsyncCallForwardListWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //List<Request_model> thisList = newList;
        //List<Tn_Parent> thisList = listDataParent;
        List<Request_model> thisList = lvList;
        System.out.println("there2: " + thisList.size());
        for (int y = 0; y< thisList.size(); y++){
            //Request_model model = thisList.get(y);
            //Tn_Parent model = thisList.get(y);
            Request_model model = thisList.get(y);
            if(model.isSelected()){
                if(action.equals("deny")){
                    //getComment = model.getApproverComment();
                    getComment = model.getApprComments();
                }else
                    getComment = "This request is " + ACTION_MSG + " by " + model.getUser_fullName() + " via mobile app";
                //getComment = "This request is " + ACTION_MSG + " by " + model.getApproverName() + " via mobile app";
                taskActivity_forward = model.getTaskActivity();

                getRequestID = model.getRequestId();
                System.out.println("testing");

                db.addInfo(new Request_model(model.getRequestId()));
                System.out.println("requestid: " + getRequestID);

                ForwardWebService();

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

AsyncCallListWS

```
private class AsyncCallListWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressbar);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Typeface dsr = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), getResources().getString(R.string.droid_sans));
        textView1.setTypeface(dsr);
        System.out.println("here1");

        isThereAnyRequest = false;

        if(lvAdapter!=null) {
            lvAdapter.clear();
            lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //listDataParent = new ArrayList<Tn_Parent>();
        listPending();
        System.out.println("here2");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dismissLoadingDialog();
        System.out.println("here3");
        selectAll.setChecked(false);

        if(getContext()!=null) {
            lvAdapter = new Tn_ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), lvList, selectAll);
            listView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        if (isThereAnyRequest){

            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //selectAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            checkBox_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_request_noti.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else{
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //selectAll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            checkBox_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_request_noti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }
}
}
```

I have this somewhere else to trigger the asynctask.

```
new AsyncCallForwardListWS().execute();
new AsyncCallListWS().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Both asynctasks really run together at the same time but it is so weird that the for loop in AsyncCallForwardListWS will not loop according to the number of checkbox that I have selected. Please help.

Comment: Why you posted all that code and all that explanations about "Async" AsyncTasks, if you actual question is about checking items in `ListView` or `RecyclerView`? Post your list adapter and how you change items in your `lvList` in order to make them `isSelected`.

Comment: you can run one task in background without showing loader, in ui thread...

Comment: @Divers because i have confirmed that my checkbox is fine. The problem now is the for loop of the asynctask. it is not looping according to the numbers of checkbox that i have selected.

Comment: @ApoorvMehrotra can u elaborate more? i dont really get u

Comment: what i mean to say is that you have 2 aync tasks for 2 different  tasks, so as per  priority show loader in first task "loading Data" & also run the second async task in background without loader code in background. Also keep  one thing in mind start second async task in the post block of the first one so that your main priority code executes first .If you are not clear i have a code related to this i can share that.

Answer (score 0):

did System.out.println("there2: " + thisList.size()); show the exact number of the list?
if not try

```
List<Request_model> thisList=new List<Request_model>(); 
thisList.addAll(lvList);
//at post of
List<Request_model> thisList = lvList;
```

Comment: @Mahdouani yes. the list size is correct i just wonder why the is the for loop is not looping